# Issue with input field contained in table row , not been able to set value for them

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I got stuck with issue. I had tried hard to get out of this but I am not been able to solve it. I am setting value for input field against table row but values 
are getting set for hidden row. I have explained this code further below.

I am cloning table row by this function:

```
      $('.table-add').click(function () {

        // var $tr = $TABLE.find('tr.hide');
        // var $clone = $tr.clone(true).addClass('hide table-line');

        // $tr.removeClass('hide table-line');

        var $clone = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').clone(true).removeClass('hide table-line');            
        hid = $TABLE.find('tr.hide').attr('id');
        // //Assigning every table row a unique ID
        var max=0;
        $('table').find('tr').each(function(){
            var id=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
            if (id>=max){
               max = id;
             }
         });

         //cloning row with new ID  
         $clone.attr('id', parseInt(max)+1);
        // $clone.find('input.myinput').tagsinput('removeAll');
         // $TABLE.find('table').append($tr);

         $clone.appendTo( $('#'+hid).parent() );
        });
```

Every row has a both td fields one of them is icon on which modal form opens: and second one is tagsinput input field. Please note that hidden row also contain both tds.

```
       <td>
            <span id="modelbox" data-target="#myModal" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </td>

     <td>    
          <input contenteditable="false" name="unique_tag" 
          class = "myinput" id="tagsinputid" data-role="tagsinput"/> 
     </td>
```

Below td tag is like that against existing rows.

```
          <td>    
          <input contenteditable="false" name="unique_tag" value= "{{ d|get_item:"unique_tag" }}" 
          class = "myinput" id="tagsinputid" data-role="tagsinput" />
          </td>
```

for hidden tr row it is like that:

```
        <td>    
          <input name="unique_tag" 
          class = "myinput" id="tagsinputid" data-role="tagsinput"/> 
        </td>
```

Now On modal form submit button, I want to get that table row against which it is clicked:

For example:

```
Table 
    row1 + 
    row2 +
    row3 + (hidden row)
```

On click of 2nd row + icon I want to get row2 id which is I am getting right against this code and setting value in next td in tags input against that row as well but this does not work right though.

```
      //click on span1 element
      $('.modal-body-inner').on("click", "span.span1", function(){
          var t = $(this).text();               
          $(this).toggleClass("myclass");
      });

      //Click on model box
      $('tr #modelbox').click(function() {
         var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
         var tbid = $row.attr('id'); // table row ID
         $('#myModal').data('current', tbid); //save current tbid
         var fieldOption = []
         $row.find('#words option').each(function() { fieldOption.push($(this).val()); });
         console.log(fieldOption);

          $('.modal-body-inner').html('');
          for(var i = 0, size = fieldOption.length; i < size ; i++){
                var item = fieldOption[i];
                $('.modal-body-inner').append("<span class=span1 > "+ item + "</span>");
          }
      });



      $('#modelformbuttonclick').click(function() {
          var tableRowId =  $('#myModal').data('current');
          c = '#' + tableRowId;
          //removing all tags if anyone updates tags
          $(c+ ' input.myinput').tagsinput('removeAll');
          var count=1; var color = ["Europe","America","Australia","Africa","Asia", "Asia2", "Africa2"];

          $('.modal-body-inner span.myclass').each(function() {
              c = '#' + tableRowId;
              var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length);
              $(c + '  input.myinput').tagsinput('add', { "name": "tagsdata", "value": $(this).text() , "text": $(this).text(), "continent": color[randomNumber]});
              count = count+1;
          });
          submitForm();
      });



<!-- Modal Form -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Choose Remarks for your students </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- <input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" /> -->
    <div class="modal-body-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button> -->
      <button type="button" id = "modelformbuttonclick" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

After execution of this code, that value that I set in tagsinput input field are not visible against that row(row2) but that are set inside hidden row(row3+) which is confusing me, Why this happens, what I have done wrong here. On debugging of this code, I am getting value of c
right which is 2 not 3 but why it is not showing tagsinput values against 2nd row but showing it against 3rd row.

Comment: Are you sure `$('#myModal').data('current')` contains the correct row ID? It looks like the code that uses it is correct.

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? It's really hard to tell what's going on with the limited bits you posted. Use a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make the code executable here.

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but you're creating duplicate IDs like `id="modelbox"` when you clone the rows.

Comment: if I assign them unique modal id, will it solve the problem. I don't think so because I  had debug code above, table id always return correct but it is only setting values against hidden row which is I don't know why

Comment: Like I said, I don't know if it's related. If you every try to use `$("#modelid")` you'll have problems, but that doesn't appear in the code you posted.

Comment: If you don't post enough code for us to see the problem, we probably can't help you.

Comment: you are right but what else you want to me to post here. I can post it there is no any issue with that.

Comment: Post all the HTML needed to run the Javascript that you posted.

Comment: may be it is helpful for you now. Inserted new code

Comment: Please convert it to Stack Snippet so we can execute it.